# can not debug with flutter null-safety flutter-dependencies

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging, flutter-dependencies, null-safety

i can run my app only using
Flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
my mobile attached my my lab top samsung M21
using android studio

flutter version Flutter 2.2.1
dart version  Dart 2.13.1
on windows 10
my app it is a template i bought it from themeforest i dont have any support from them
this my first time with null-safety
i have made some change because of that
and i have run

dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
dart pub upgrade --null-safety
dart pub get
dart migrate

but when click on deubg button
it does not work at all
this is my terminal

```
[  +88 ms] executing: [D:\flutter\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +121 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 02c026b03cd31dd3f867e5faeb7e104cce174c5f
[   +1 ms] executing: [D:\flutter\flutter/] git tag --points-at 02c026b03cd31dd3f867e5faeb7e104cce174c5f
[ +102 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 02c026b03cd31dd3f867e5faeb7e104cce174c5f
[        ] 2.2.1
[   +6 ms] executing: [D:\flutter\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +73 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [D:\flutter\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +72 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +163 ms] executing: [D:\flutter\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +97 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[ +101 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +63 ms] executing: C:\Users\hdarwish\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices -l
[  +71 ms] List of devices attached
           R58NC4TZSJA            device product:a12nnxx model:SM_A125F device:a12 transport_id:1
[   +8 ms] C:\Users\hdarwish\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s R58NC4TZSJA shell getprop
[ +113 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +48 ms] "flutter run" took 327ms.
[  +20 ms] Target file "run" not found.
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      FlutterCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1322:9)
           #1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:448:19)
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1148:11)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +253 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 251ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: did you try --no-sound-null-safety flag like this `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`?